# Did Skydiver Luke Aikins jump 25000 feet without parachute?

Tags: parachutes

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6qF_fzEI4wU) and this [article](http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2016/07/30/488083554/luke-aikins-becomes-first-person-to-jump-from-a-plane-without-a-parachute) skydiver attempts to jump without a parachute.

I can see in the video that his front(stomach) is bigger and possibly hiding something. Did he have the parachute hidden in the front and planning to open only in case his dropping gets out of the route and misses the target? Or is there a total prove he didn't have any parachute at all?

Comment: Oh, that is _cool_.

Comment: What kind of evidence are you looking for? NPR (the article you linked to) is a pretty reliable source.

Comment: Do they say anywhere that he will have the parachute for the safety reasons? He won't use it though only if things go wrong? I can't believe they would put him in such a risk without the backup plan. It doesn't make any sense to me to risk someone's life for not big enough reason.

Comment: The final paragraph of the article reads: 'According to The Associated Press, "Just before climbing into a plane to make the jump, Aikins said he had been ordered to wear a parachute but indicated he wouldn't open it. As the plane was climbing to 25,000 feet above the drop zone he said the requirement had been lifted and he took off the chute."' So it sounds like he didn't have a parachute at all.

Comment: What is a "total prove"?

Comment: @sklivvz doesn't matter. Answers here will just present the best evidence behind the claim. Whether it is a "total prove" is a red herring.

Comment: @Dawn what constitutes valid evidence is certainly a question that matters, since the OP is dismissing the official reports.

Comment: The asker doesn't get to determine what valid evidence is. We just present the best evidence and if the asker doesn't accept that that is their problem.

Comment: @Grasper consider that the guy trains military special forces in skydiving for a living. With his skills and experience, him missing a target in controlled freefall is probably less likely than me crashing my car into a wall next time I drive, or an airline pilot pranging their plane nose-first into the runway. People do life-endangering things they're trained for all the time.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard, you can post it as an answer, thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Alkemade  and no net...